# E4X, filter to retrieve subnode value

Tags: actionscript-3, e4x

this is a small piece of a bigger XML:

```
<menu first="modelID">
        <model>
            <id>modelID</id>
            <nome>Name</nome>
            <cover type="img">./img/cover.png</cover>
            <sub value="Images|Audio" />
        </model>
        <model>
            <id>modelID2</id>
...
</model>
```

Using E4X I easily **retrieve the value from the menu "first" attribute** and I save it to a variable (**firstModel**).

Now I want to retrieve the **cover type** and the **cover text()** of the node whose **id** equals to **firstModel**. How can I do? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var firstModel : String = "modelID"; //your parsed value here
trace(a.model.(id == firstModel).cover.@type);
trace(a.model.(id == firstModel).cover);
```

output:

```
[trace] img
[trace] ./img/cover.png
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying with "descendants" but it seems it doesn't work inside parentheses.